# Is there a way to create a closure that computes an nth degree polynomial with random coefficients in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, polynomials

So the idea is to have a function that returns a closure of degree n with random coefficients. This might be useful for comparing root finding methods, as we can automate the creation of a function to evaluate, for example.
Appending any operations to a closure's return would be an even more powerful resource, so let me know if there is some way to do that.

The code should look as following:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
fn create_func(n: u8) -> impl Fn(f64) -> f64 { 
    let mut cst = vec![];
    for _ in 0..n{
        cst.push(rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=20)  as f64);
        // establish the coefficients by randomly generating them
    }
    move |x| cst[0]*x + cst[1]*x.powf(1.) + /*...*/ cst[n- 1]*x.powf(n as f64)
}
```

So obviously the last part isn't really a valid way of expressing the rest of the closure we *want to* return, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a sum, so turn your sequence into an iterator that will be summed.

```rs
move |x| {
    cst.iter()
        .zip(0..=n as i32)
        .map(|(&c, exp)| c * x.powi(exp))
        .sum()
}
```

For each item, you need the element from `cst` (`iter`) and its exponent (`zip`). You can construct terms one at a time from those (`map`), and then sum all terms together (`sum`).

I've also fixed your number of terms (yours doesn't have the *x^0* term) and used `sample_iter`, which is faster than calling `thread_rng` every time. And I've switched to `powi` since all the exponents are integers.

```rs
pub fn create_func(n: u8) -> impl Fn(f64) -> f64 {
    let cst: Vec<f64> = rand::thread_rng()
        .sample_iter(rand::distributions::Uniform::new_inclusive(0, 20))
        .map(|n| n as f64)
        .take(n as usize + 1)
        .collect();

    move |x| {
        cst.iter()
            .zip(0..=n as i32)
            .map(|(&c, exp)| c * x.powi(exp))
            .sum()
    }
}
```

Comment: You could `.enumerate()` instead of reusing `n`.

Comment: I left `n` there to show what it corresponds to. Also I don't really like using `enumerate` when I don't need a `usize`.

Comment: Ah but imo it's all too easy to make an off by one error (for example forget the `=`) and `enumerate` completely avoids that mistake. Also you have to cast anyways since `n` isn't the correct type to begin with.

Comment: The alternative is `zip(0..)` which doesn't have those problems.

Comment: Except `zip(1..)` is still off by one, (admittedly a rarer error but when translating algorithms from maths not unheard of)

Answer (score 1):

Other ways of expressing polynomial are as:

```
P_fold_n(x) = (…(((x + a_1) * x + a_2) * x + a_3)…) * x + a_n
```

and

```
P_map_n(x) = (x + a_1) * (x + a_2) * (x + a_3) … * (x + a_n)
```

which lead to the following implementations:

```rust
fn poly_via_fold(coeffs: Vec<f64>) -> impl Fn(f64) -> f64 {
    move |x: f64| coeffs.iter().fold(1.0, |res, a| res * x + a)
}

fn poly_via_map(coeffs: Vec<f64>) -> impl Fn(f64) -> f64 {
    move |x: f64| coeffs.iter().map(|a| x + a).product()
}
```

Comment: The `P_map_n` method does not compute the value of an equivalent polinomial, it differs in magnitude! One could generate different coefficients or calculate them from the original ones to preserve the equivalence though.

Comment: @cafce25, I think you mean to say that the coefficients used in my code are different from the ones you get with `P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 ... x^n`, which is true. But if your coefficients are random anyway, then you probably don't care much about the meaning of the coefficients.

Comment: If they're truely completely random yes, but that's just not a thing, OP generated the coefficients with a specific distribution, which your `P_map_n` changes. That might or might not be acceptable.